# Как улучшить качество картинки?

Tags: php, изображения

Здравствуйте
Стоит задача, в интернет маназине http://site.ru нужно улучшить качество картинки.
Расширение: 600*450, формат: jpg, средний размер картинки: 15-25 КВ

Как можно их качество как то улучшить, не прибегая к photoshop'y ?
Спасибо.

Как пример:

[image]

Comment: нужна ретушь? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PHP есть библиотека для обработки изображений, **ImageMagick**.

Посмотрите функции `adaptiveSharpenImage`, `contrastImage`, `edgeImage` и `gammaImage` на [странице документации](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). Они работают примерно как соответствующие фильтры в Photoshop.